# Transformer ratio test ...deviation close to the limit

Tags: power, transformer, transmission

When conducted ratio test .33/11 Transformer gave a ratio deviation of 0.48 % for first tap ..it is the commissioning test .the Standard deviation is 0.5 % .for all other taps the deviation is well below the limit ..Is it an indication of any inter turn faults ??

Answer (score 1):

1 standard deviation (gaussian) means that 68.2% per cent of the time the "variable" will be within the limits so if the standard deviation is 0.5 then, there is a 68% probability that the variable (turns ratio) will be within that limit: -

[image]

1 sigma is not excessive as a test so maybe consider 3 sigma as the test criteria?

For further reading try [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) wiki page.

Note that if there is one turn shorted on a transformer then it affects ALL other turn ratios and can cause a fire - an extra test might be to measure the impedance into the primary under no load conditions to verify that the magnetization inductance is what it is expected to be. This will certainly uncover the possibility of a shorted turn.

Comment: It was a mistake i used ...Standard deviation ...i Actually mean by IEC Standard the allowed deviation is 0.5%  from the Actual ratio ....now coming to the second part ..only in tap 1 the complete turns will be energised ...as tap is increased (tap isin primary ) the number of turns are reduced ..

Comment: Yeah magnetization current is gonna reveal the thing ..but what making me confused is the limit is 0.5% but the ratio is still within limit (even if it is close )